# change array index in for loop before push in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var array = [23,34,56,35]
```

I want to do this using a for loop in javascript

```
var array = [
   2:23
   3:34
   4:56
   5:35
]
```

instead of

```
var array = [
   0:23
   1:34
   2:56
   3:35
]
```

Comment: While you *can*, sparse arrays are almost always a *pretty bad idea*. Why do you want a sparse array?

Answer (score 1):

You can use forEach of array, to do:

```js
var array = [23,34,56,35];
var result = [];
array.forEach((current,index)=>{
  result[index+2] = current;
});
console.log(result);
```